# How do I enable Integration Services (SSIS) in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, installation

I cannot start SSIS in SQL Server 2008. Here is a screenshot of SQL Server installer. Where should I begin to enable/install Integration Services in SQL Server 2008?

[image]

Comment: Install integration services by clicking install then choose integration service.

Comment: @siva ... I think you answered this question.. but then took your answer off. Could you please put it back?

Comment: Can you accept the answer, it was the right way to solve my issue.

Answer (score 43):

Here are the screenshots of installation steps taken using **`SQL Server 2008 R2`** installer. The steps listed below should give you an idea to install necessary components of `SQL Server 2008`.

On the SQL Server installation media, right-click on **`Setup.exe`** and select **Run as administrator**.

On `SQL Server Installation Center`, click *Installation* and then click *New installation or add features to an existing installation*.

[image: Installer]

Click **OK** on `Setup Support Rules` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup. If there are warnings or failures on Setup Support Rules, take necessary actions to fix them.

Click **Install** on `Setup Support Files` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup.

Click **Next >** on `Setup Support Rules` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup. If there are warnings or failures on Setup Support Rules, take necessary actions to fix them.

On the `Installation Type` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup, select either *New installation or add shared features* or select *Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008 R2* and pick an appropriate instance name. Click **Next >**

[image: Installation type]

Enter the product key on `Product Key` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup and click **Next >**

Check `I accept license terms`, if you choose to accept the terms and conditions and click **Next >** on `License Terms` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup.

Select *SQL Server Feature Installation* on `Setup Role` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup, click **Next >**

On `Feature Selection` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup, you need to decide what you would like to install.

- If you need only the Business Intelligence Development Studio for SSIS packages development, then install only the Business Intelligence Development Studio.
- If you need the Integration Services to deploy and run the SSIS packages, choose Integration Services. **`NOTE`**: I would recommend reading Licensing requirements on MSDN or Microsoft website before you choose this option.

Below screenshot shows BIDS installation for SSIS packages development and other client only components.

[image: Feature Selection]

Read the details and click **Next >** on `Installation Rules` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup.

Read the details and click**Next >** on `Disk Space Requirements` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup.

Read the details and click **Next >** on `Error Reporting` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup.

Click **Next >** on `Installation Configuration Rules` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup. If there are warnings or failures on Installation Configuration Rules, take necessary actions to fix them.

Verify the components and click **Install** on `Ready to Install` step of SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup.

Once the install is complete, the status wizard will appear. Click Close if everything is successful else take necessary action if the install fails.

Hope that helps.