# What tools do I need to create SSIS packages on Windows 8?

Tags: ssis

I am running Windows 8 and need to develop SSIS packages.

The version of SSIS packages I need are SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am new to SSIS but it is my understanding that I need to install SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010 in order to be able to create an Integration Services project (which will contain my SSIS package).Is this correct?

Does anyone know what I need to install? I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010 Premium however I do not get the option of Integration Services project template.

I have Visual Studio 2012 installed but it is my understanding that VS2012 cannot be used for SSIS package creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need *`Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)`* if you want to create SSIS packages with SQL Server 2008 R2 version. BIDS uses Visual Studio 2008 Shell. Visual Studio 2010 is not required for SSIS development with SQL Server 2008 R2.

However, if you are using SQL Server 2012 then you need SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) which uses Visual Studio 2010 Shell.

Answer to the below SO question contains the steps to install *Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)* using *SQL Server 2008 R2* installer.

[How do I enable Integration Services (SSIS) in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551255/how-do-i-enable-integration-services-ssis-in-sql-server-2008/14564823#14564823)

Comment: I have tried installing VS2008 R2 and I do not get the "Feature Selection" link.

Comment: sorry, i meant SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: BIDS has been renamed "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools" I think - see http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 and SSIS development for SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 works fine.

SQL Server 2005 will use the Visual Studio 2005 shell (devenv) for BIDS (Business Intelligence Designer Studio)

SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 use the Visual Studio 2008 shell for BIDS

SQL Server 2012 uses Visual Studio 2010's shell for SSDT (SQL Server Development Tools). They have a roadmap for using Visual Studio 2012 environment as well but have not released the project templates yet.

For all those choices, you never need to have a Visual Studio installation. The SQL Server installer will put the shell onto your machine and the associated ssis/ssrs/ssas project types when you select the option in the installer.

Comment: So all I need to do is install SQL Server 2008 R2? I have done that 3 times today and after I have not found Business Intelligence Designer Studuo in start menu.

Comment: Yes, see @siva's excellent answer on their linked question. http://i.stack.imgur.com/qwfNu.png

Comment: I do not get the same UI as that screen shot, I do not get the option "Feature Selection".