# Cannot find Integrations service in connection window ssms

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I'm trying to connect to an instance of Integration services with SSMS 2008. I cannot find the Integration services in the drop down list of server type. I can only see database engine and SQL Server compact. What can cause this issue? Is it possible that I missed a feature during installation

[image]

Comment: Try downloading the latest version of SSMS. Do you still have the issue then?

Comment: I have the latest version of SSMS installed , but it does not support connection to an old version of Integration service.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what you are seeing when you are missing the Integration Service option.

Comment: I have added screenshot. I can only see these 2 options

Comment: That's not that latest version of SSMS.

Comment: The screenshot is not the latest version. I'm showing what I have in version 2008 when I try to connect as @TabAlleman requested.

Comment: I'll confirm this tomorrow, but I'm confident that SSMS 2017 does support the old SSIS connection. As it supports 2008 onwards. I'm pretty confident I had to use it before we upgraded our 2008 server last year.

Comment: Just had a double check, and SSMS 2017 does indeed support connecting to Integration Services; and i don't mean the SSIS Catalog. I'd suggest downloading this version and trying checking if you still have the same problem (I imagine you won't).

Comment: I have a 2008R2 SSMS installed, and I have IS, AS, and RS connections as Server Type options, but I don't have SQL Server Compact.   My guess is that you installed the SSMS that came with a non-enterprise edition of SQL Server, like Compact or Express.   See if you can get a more robust edition of SQL Server and install SSMS from it.  When you open SSMS and do Help>About, what version do you have?   Mine is 10.50.2500.0.

Answer (score 0):

Integration Services is not a Server Type that you connect to. You must install the SQL Server Integration Services catalog on a specific server instance. Once Integration Services is installed, it will create a new database called SSISDB. That is how you manage SSIS packages on SQL Server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/integration-services-ssis-server-and-catalog

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471509(v=sql.120).aspx

Note: To add Integration services for 2008R2: [How do I enable Integration Services (SSIS) in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551255/how-do-i-enable-integration-services-ssis-in-sql-server-2008)

If Integration Services is already installed on the Server, then try uninstalling and re-installing SSMS.

Comment: That is true for SQL Server 2012, this is not the case on 2008R2, which the OP implies they have.