# Where can I get Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2008, ssis-2008, vsta

A few weeks ago I was cleaning up an old server which one of my colleagues still uses for SSIS packages with Visual Studio 2008. I uninstalled VSTA 2008, because I didn't think we'd need it, but I was wrong.

Now we can't open Script Tasks anymore and I can't seem to find the setup to reinstall VSTA 2008.
It doesn't seem to be included in Visual Studio 2008 either. There's only a setup for VSTOR, but I don't need that.

So the only hope I have is that somebody somewhere knows where I can get a setup of VSTA from over 10 years ago.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300795/what-to-do-when-your-question-is-marked-as-duplicate-but-you-dont-see-how-so -

Comment: Please keep your language to a professional tone.

Comment: When you install the Integration Services from SQL Server 2008 it also install SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio (Visual Studio) that contains all components needed. It it is already installed try to run a SQL Server repair installation

Comment: @BaummitAugen i think the OP is right, these question are related but there are not duplicates, i voted to reopen the question but since the sql-server tag was removed i can't reopen it immediately. Can you reopen it as a moderator?

Comment: Reopened at request if the original Mjolnir. cc @Hadi

Comment: @BaummitAugen thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VSTA (Visual Studio Tools for application) is installed with the Business Intelligence development studio 2008 which is a part of the SQL Server 2008 installation. **It is not related to Visual Studio installation**.

You can try to repair the SQL Server installation or to remove and reinstall the SSIS and Business Intelligence Development Studio features:

- [How do I enable Integration Services (SSIS) in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551255/how-do-i-enable-integration-services-ssis-in-sql-server-2008)

Also check the following links they contains helpful information:

- [Downloading Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2.0 -ENU](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2698775a-689b-4323-842d-4c64d21aeaac/downloading-microsoft-visual-studio-tools-for-applications-20-enu?forum=vsta)
- [How to install Visual Studio Tools for Applications?](http://sharepointgoogle.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-install-visual-studio-tools-for.html)
- [VSTA setup and configuration troubles for SSIS 2008 and R2 installations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jason_howell/2010/08/18/vsta-setup-and-configuration-troubles-for-ssis-2008-and-r2-installations/)

---

After searching for a [standalone installation of VSTA SDK 2.0 enu 9.0 on the Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search?q=%22Visual+Studio+Tools+for+Applications+2.0%22) it looks like the download link is removed and only 2012+ versions can be found.